# javacode into input tag

Tags: javascript

Ive got a java function but I want to put it in input tag. I want to do this but hmtl doesn't displaye it:

```
function ff
  {
  x.innerHTML="This is it <input id='id' name='name'  class='box' value=' " CODE    " '> ";
  }
```

any ideas?

Comment: what does that `CODE` refer to? Is it really a Java method running on some server?

Comment: Does your java code have any single quotes in it? That would break the concatenation...

Comment: `function ff{...}` should be `function ff(){...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming CODE is your code, you aren't concatenating the strings, which is why it's not showing up.

Comment: Try: x.innerHTML= "This is it <input id='id' name='name'  class='box' value=' " + CODE  + " '> ";.  Again, I assume CODE is a string, containing the code you want to show.

Comment: @user1823527 be certain to mark this as the accepted answer, since user1161318 helped you correct your issue.